# Using jquery load function in combination with forms

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Currently developing a new website and looking to use jQuery's `load()` function to load content from different html pages into my main page.

`load()` works fine. Here's my current code.
Main.html page in which content is loaded:

```
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Javascript with the `load()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#answer").load( "game1content.html #p1Answer");
```

game1content.html content to load:

```
<div id="p1Answer">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <form id="answer1Form">
        <select name="answer1" id="answer1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Website 1</option>
            <option value="2">Website 2</option>
            <option value="3">Website 3</option>
            <option value="4">Website 4</option>
        </select>
        <button id="submitButton">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

So it loads html correctly into the answer div. Perfect.

Now the challenge is that when I submit the form that's loaded, it refreshes the page. When I have the game1content content in the main.html file, instead of using the `load()` it doesn't reload and works fine. But if I use the `load()` function, it does reload and also changes the url.

Here's my function on submit:

```
$( "#answer1Form" ).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log ("clicked");
});
```

I've tried Googling this issue, but can't find much. Also, tried changing `.submit` to `onclick` etc, but same result. Any ideas?

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you call `.load`, it fetch the page content and adds DOM elements but not bind them to events, so the `form` behave like it should, refresh the page.

In order to prevent the form from refreshing you should listen to `.submit()` exactly like you do in *game1content.html* **after** the DOM elements are added.

Like this:

```js
$("#answer").load( "game1content.html #p1Answer", function() {
  $( "#answer1Form" ).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
  });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for your help, makes my day!

Comment: Any time :) Good luck.